# Add element to OLED display via PIL/Python without erasing rest

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, hardware

I have a SH1106 display connected to my Raspberry Pi that I'm controlling using luma.oled.

I can display all kind of content in different fonts, which is great. However, I can't figure out how to add something to what's currently being displayed without refreshing the whole display. My code is like this:

```
from os import system
import serial
from time import sleep
from luma.core.interface.serial import i2c
from luma.core.render import canvas
from luma.oled.device import sh1106
from PIL import ImageFont

# config display
device = sh1106(i2c(port=1, address=0x3C), rotate=0)
device.clear()
FA_solid = ImageFont.truetype('/home/pi/Desktop/tests/fa-solid-900.ttf', 16)
FA_regular = ImageFont.truetype('/home/pi/Desktop/tests/fa-regular-400.ttf', 16)
text_large = ImageFont.truetype('/home/pi/Desktop/tests/coolvetica condensed rg.ttf', 48)
text_small = ImageFont.truetype('/home/pi/Desktop/tests/coolvetica condensed rg.ttf', 16)

# display things
def show_icon(code):
    with canvas(device) as draw:
        draw.text((112, 0), text=code, font=FA_solid, fill="white")
        
def large_text(content, paddingleft =0, paddingtop =0):
    with canvas(device) as draw:
        draw.text((0, 0), text=content, font=text_large, fill="white")
        
def small_text(content, paddingleft =0, paddingtop =0):
    with canvas(device) as draw:
        draw.text((0, 0), text=content, font=text_small, fill="white")

show_icon("\uf124")
sleep(2)
large_text("Hi ;)")
sleep(10)
device.clear()
```

This display an icon from fontawesome in the upper right corner, then clears the screen and displays Hi. How can I change this to display the icon + hi? Ideally I'd have "zones" on the screen where I can change the icon zone while keeping the text displayed and vice versa. Thanks!

EDIT --------------------

Here's my code, adapted from Mark's answer below. Better but still not there yet. The Zones 1 and 3 stay the same while 2 is updated but when I redraw the screen, it is blank for half a second and then updates, which I don't want.

```
def UpdateDisplay(z1,z2,z3):
    """Pass in the three zones and they will be sent to the screen"""

    device = sh1106(i2c(port=1, address=0x3C), rotate=0)

    # Make a black canvas the size of the entire screen
    whole = Image.new("1", (128,64))

    # Now paste in the 3 zones to form the whole
    whole.paste(z1, (2,2))        # zone1 at top-left
    whole.paste(z2, (66,2))       # zone2 at top-right
    whole.paste(z3, (2,34))       # zone3 across the bottom

    # I save the image here, but you would write it to the screen with "device.display()"
    device.display(whole)
    return

# Make zone1 dark grey and annotate it
z1 = Image.new("1", (60,30))
z1draw = ImageDraw.Draw(z1)
z1draw.text((10,10),"Zone1", fill="white")

# Make zone2 mid-grey and annotate it
z2 = Image.new("1", (60,30))
z2draw = ImageDraw.Draw(z2)
z2draw.text((10,10),"Zone2", fill="white")

# Make zone3 light grey and annotate it
z3 = Image.new("1", (124,28))
z3draw = ImageDraw.Draw(z3)
z3draw.text((10,10),"Zone3", fill="white")

# Blit all zones to display
UpdateDisplay(z1,z2,z3)

sleep(5)

# Make zone2 mid-grey and annotate it
z2 = Image.new("1", (60,30))
z2draw = ImageDraw.Draw(z2)
z2draw.text((10,10),"Zone2 changed", fill="white")

UpdateDisplay(z1,z2,z3)
```

Comment: Sorry Mark - I haven’t had time to test it yet (COVID) but it does look the part. Will get back to you if it doesn’t work but in the meantime - accepted!

Comment: You can try saving the images to .png files and then look at the files and see what's went wrong. This will tell you if the issue is with the creation of 'whole' or with updating the display with whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I mostly figured it out:

```
from luma.core.interface.serial import i2c
from luma.core.render import canvas
from luma.oled.device import sh1106
from PIL import ImageFont, Image, ImageDraw    

### setting up display using LUMA oled
device = sh1106(i2c(port=1, address=0x3C), rotate=0)
device.clear()

### Initialize drawing zone (aka entire screen)
output = Image.new("1", (128,64))
add_to_image = ImageDraw.Draw(output)

### I have the exterior temp and altitude I want to display. Each has an assigned zone for the icon (FontAwesome) and the data
# temp_ext
temp_zone = [(14,44), (36,64)]
temp_start = (14,44)
temp_icon_zone = [(0,48), (15,64)]
temp_icon_start = (3,48)
add_to_image.text(temp_icon_start, "\uf2c9", font=FA_solid, fill="white")

### every time I have a new reading, I basically draw a black rectangle over what I had and the rewrite the text
add_to_image.rectangle(temp_zone, fill="black", outline = "black")
add_to_image.text(temp_start, str(temp_c), font=text_medium, fill="white")
device.display(output)
```

This enables me to only update the part of the screen I want, leaving the rest as is and, crucially, not having a blank screen for half a second when rewriting info. Feel free to suggest optimizations!

I still need to look into memory usage, it feels kinda sluggish when the different zones are updating at once. But it works!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an SH1106 to test with and I have never used the `luma` library, so there may be a much simpler way of doing what you want. If so, maybe someone will kindly ping me and I'll delete this answer.

I have used `PIL` quite a lot, so I looked in [here](https://github.com/rm-hull/luma.examples/blob/master/examples/animated_gif.py) around line 28:

```
background = Image.new("RGB", device.size, "white")
background.paste(frame.resize(size, resample=Image.LANCZOS), posn)
device.display(background.convert(device.mode))
```

So, it seems you can create a `PIL Image` and send it to the display like that. The first line creates a blank white canvas the same size as the entire display, the second line pastes another `PIL Image` onto the canvas at the specified position and the last line sends the image to the display. So, all you need to do, is define your `N` *"zones"* separately and draw in them separately (each being a `PIL Image`), then when you want to update the display, paste your `N` zones in at the positions you want them and send the completed picture to the display.

Sorry I can't be more precise, but I have nothing to test with. Here's a little example with 3 zones that can be drawn individually and then assembled to a whole before calling `device.display()`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def UpdateDisplay(z1,z2,z3):
   """Pass in the three zones and they will be sent to the screen"""

   # Make a black canvas the size of the entire screen
   whole = Image.new("RGB", (128,64), (0,0,0))

   # Now paste in the 3 zones to form the whole
   whole.paste(z1, (2,2))        # zone1 at top-left
   whole.paste(z2, (66,2))       # zone2 at top-right
   whole.paste(z3, (2,34))       # zone3 across the bottom

   # I save the image here, but you would write it to the screen with "device.display()"
   whole.save('result.png')
   return

# Make zone1 dark grey and annotate it
z1 = Image.new("RGB", (60,30), (64,64,64))
z1draw = ImageDraw.Draw(z1)
z1draw.text((10,10),"Zone1")

# Make zone2 mid-grey and annotate it
z2 = Image.new("RGB", (60,30), (128,128,128))
z2draw = ImageDraw.Draw(z2)
z2draw.text((10,10),"Zone2")

# Make zone3 light grey and annotate it
z3 = Image.new("RGB", (124,28), (192,192,192))
z3draw = ImageDraw.Draw(z3)
z3draw.text((10,10),"Zone3")

# Blit all zones to display
UpdateDisplay(z1,z2,z3)

# Now change just zone 2 and update display
z2.paste("red", (0,0,z2.width,z2.height))
UpdateDisplay(z1,z2,z3)
```

Here is the original display:

[image]

And here again after updating just zone2:

[image]

Comment: I have adapted your code to try out your approach on a black and white display and it's a kind of semi-victory: it works in that it does not require me to specify each zone all the time, BUT: it still redraws the entire screen, leading to it being all black for a second and then updated... might be due to my screen too, it's a SH1106. Will update the question with the new code

Comment: Ok, thank you for the update. I'll put my thinking cap back on...